# SQL Oracle use String for number

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle, numbers

I got table for an Oracle database.

This table is called `TABLE1` with two columns.

Table 1:

```
numberValue         wordValue

    1               Auto
    3               LKW
    4               Boot
    6               Fahrrad
    7               E-Auto
```

In my output I have a column that gives numbers back (not from table 1) - now I want that this numbers are replaced by the values in table1.wordValue.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me a link to an example? I am a total beginner with this

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=join+example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, a simple join condition will give you your desired result:

```
SELECT wordValue 
FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2
     ON TABLE1.numberValue=TABLE2.attr;
```

Change `TABLE2` to the table where the output is coming from and `attr` to the attribute of the table